# Get the correct studentID from StudentTable by entering incomplete IDnumber

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some `studentID`s that are missing some characters from the end. I need to find the closest match (correct ID number) from the `Student` table.

My script below is taking time to do as I have many students.

Please advise on a better way. I would like to add all incomplete IDs and get the correct one like

```
if studentID like ('JG853102%','SE686104%','SE686104%')
```

then get the closest match from my table.

```sql
SELECT First Name, Surname, StudentID
FROM StudentTable
WHERE StudentID like 'JG853102%'
  OR StudentID like 'SE686104%'
 OR StudentID like 'SE686104%'
```

Comment: please show full table schema and current execution plan

Comment: That `WHERE` is never going to be true. A value *can't* be `LIKE 'JG853102%'` **and** `LIKE 'SE686104%'`. It seems you want an `OR`. Also, the query above is actually SARGable, though an `EXISTS`  to a TVP/`VALUES` construct might be better, so I would suggest the reason it is slow is due to a lack of indexes. What indexes do you have on your table `StudentTable`?

Comment: How do **YOU** know that characters are missing? Is it simply based on the number of characters in that column? Your script - if it worked - focuses on 3 specific values (and presumably 3 specific rows) - that contradicts your statement about "add all incomplete IDs".  And TBH why is there no constraint or FK to prevent such issues?

Comment: I am sorry my mistake it is or.

Comment: Is `'Foo'` closer to `'Foop'` or `'Foon'`? Without a precise definition of "closest match" we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have *is* SARGable, however, as I mentioned in the comments the `WHERE` can *never* be true. You are checking that the value of `StudentID` starts with both `'JG853102'` **and** `'SE686104'`. This is obviously impossible as a string *cannot* start with two completely different sets of characters. You therefore most likely want an `OR`.

The reason the query is slow, however, is likely due to a lack any type of indexing. On a table with the name `StudentTable` and a column with the name `StudentID` one would *assume* that this is your `PRIMARY KEY`, which means it would be indexed already. This strongly suggests it is *not*. Based on  the value though it doesn't look like it's an always ascending value, meaning that it could likely *not* be a good candidate for a `CLUSTERED INDEX`. *If* it is always ascending, then creating your `PRIMARY KEY` as a `CLUSTERED` one would likely make the query far better:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.StudentTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_StudentTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StudentID);
```

As the `CLUSTERED INDEX` automatically includes all columns in the table, then it'll be a covering index for your columns `First` and `Surname` as well.

If the value *isn't* always ascending, then you want to create a separate index. For what we have, that would minimally be the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.StudentTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_StudentTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (StudentID);
CREATE INDEX IX_StudentTable_StudentID ON dbo.StudentTable (StudentID) INCLUDE (First, Surname);
```

If you have more columns in your table `StudentTable` then I would `INCLUDE` all of those if you can.

Finally, you might find that a Table Variable or `VALUES` construct with an `EXISTS` might be more performant than an `OR`. That would look like the following:

```sql
--VALUES
SELECT First AS [Name],
       Surname,
       StudentID
FROM dbo.StudentTable ST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (VALUES('JG853102%'),
                          ('SE686104%'))V(StudentID)
              WHERE ST.StudentID LIKE V.StudentID);
--Variable
DECLARE @IDs table (StudentID varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @IDs
VALUES('JG853102%'),
      ('SE686104%');

SELECT First AS [Name],
       Surname,
       StudentID
FROM dbo.StudentTable ST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @IDS I
              WHERE ST.StudentID LIKE I.StudentID);
```

Comment: the Value query worked perfect.Many thanks @Larnu